# .NET MAUI (.NET 6) Entity Framework DbContext SQLite

Tags: .net, entity-framework, inyeccion-de-dependencias, maui

como andan? Estoy implementando una APP Movil en .NET MAUI con Entity Framework y SQLite , en la cual, estoy haciendo referencia a un DbContext que ya uso anteriormente, debido a que la APP movil comparte las mismas entidades que la API, el problema esta cuando quiero utilizar ese DbContext en SQLite (en mi API lo uso con MySQL), por ejemplo:

API (CON MY SQL) , inyeccion de dependecias:

```
services.TryAddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddDbContext<StoreCustomersContext>(async opt =>
{
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    string originUri = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext?.Request?.Headers["originUri"];
    string connectionString = string.Empty;
    if (originUri == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(originUri))
    {
        throw new Exception("Request invalido de url.");
        //connectionString = configurations.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    }
    else
    {
        connectionString = await new ConnectionStringService().GetByUri(originUri);
    }

    opt.UseMySql(
        connectionString,
        ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)
    )
    .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
}); 

services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, MySQLProductRepository>();
services.AddScoped<IEmployeeRepository, MySQLEmployeeRepository>();

//PRODUCTS
services.AddScoped<ProductSearcher>();
services.AddScoped<ProductCreator>();   
services.AddScoped<ProductEliminator>();

//EMPLOYES
services.AddScoped<EmployeeSearcher>();
services.AddScoped<EmployeeCreator>();
```

NET MAUI APP (inyeccion de dependencias)

```
services.AddDbContext<StoreCustomersContext>(opt =>
{
    string dbPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "storesys.db");
    opt.UseSqlite($"Filename={dbPath}");
});

services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, MySQLProductRepository>();
services.AddScoped<IEmployeeRepository, MySQLEmployeeRepository>();
//PRODUCTS
services.AddScoped<ProductSearcher>();
services.AddScoped<ProductCreator>();
services.AddScoped<ProductEliminator>();

//EMPLOYES
services.AddScoped<EmployeeSearcher>();
services.AddScoped<EmployeeCreator>();
```

Como ven , en la API el contexto usa MySQL y en .NET MAUI APP el contexto usa SQLite, el problema es que para MySQL los metodos me andan bien, pero al querer usar los mismos metodos pero con el contexto en SQLite me tira error, alguien sabe porque sucede esto?

Mi repositorio base:

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : BaseModel, IAggregateRoot
{
    protected readonly StoreCustomersContext contexto;

    public Repository(StoreCustomersContext contexto)
    {
        this.contexto = contexto;    
    }

    protected DbSet<T> setearEntidad => contexto.Set<T>();

    public async Task<T> Save(T entidad)
    {
        T result;
        await entityStateModifiedManually(entidad);
        if (contexto.Entry(entidad).State == EntityState.Detached || contexto.Entry(entidad).State == EntityState.Added)
            result = (T)(await contexto.AddAsync(entidad)).Entity;
        else
            result = entidad;

        await contexto.SaveChangesAsync();

        return result;
    }

    private async Task entityStateModifiedManually(Object ObjectToRecurse)
    {
        contexto.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(
        ObjectToRecurse, node =>
        {
            var PrimaryKey = node.Entry.Property($"Id");
            var keyValue = (int)PrimaryKey.CurrentValue;

            if (keyValue == 0)
                node.Entry.State = EntityState.Added;
            else if (keyValue < 0)
                node.Entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
            else
                node.Entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        });
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> GetAll()
    {
        return await setearEntidad.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return await setearEntidad.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeString = null, bool disableTracking = true)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = contexto.Set<T>();
        if (disableTracking) query = query.AsNoTracking();

        if (predicate != null) query = query.Where(predicate);

        if (orderBy != null) return await orderBy(query).ToListAsync();

        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, List<Expression<Func<T, object>>> includes = null, bool disableTracking = true)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = contexto.Set<T>();
        if (disableTracking) query = query.AsNoTracking();

        if (includes != null) query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));

        if (predicate != null) query = query.Where(predicate);

        if (orderBy != null) return await orderBy(query).ToListAsync();

        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<T> GetById(int id)
    {
        return await setearEntidad.FindAsync(id);
    }

    public async Task<T> GetById(int id, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return await setearEntidad.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
    }

    public async Task<T> GetById(int id, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeString = null, bool disableTracking = true)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = contexto.Set<T>();
        if (disableTracking) query = query.AsNoTracking();

        if (predicate != null) query = query.Where(predicate);

        if (orderBy != null)
            return await orderBy(query).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.Equals(id));

        return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
    }

    public async Task<T> GetById(int id, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, List<Expression<Func<T, object>>> includes = null, bool disableTracking = true)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = contexto.Set<T>();
        if (disableTracking) query = query.AsNoTracking();

        if (includes != null) query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));

        if (predicate != null) query = query.Where(predicate);

        if (orderBy != null) return await orderBy(query).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.Equals(id));

        return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
    }

    public async Task<T> Delete(int id)
    {
        T entidad = await setearEntidad.FindAsync(id);
        setearEntidad.Remove(entidad);
        await contexto.SaveChangesAsync();
        return entidad;
    }
}
```

Edicion:

El error que me tira es el siguiente:

```
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Infrastructure.EntityFramework.Persistence.Shared.MySQLRepository`1.<Save>d__4[[Domain.Employees.Employee, Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext() in C:\PROGRAMACION\STORE\BACKEND\.NET 6\StoreSysBackendCustomers\StoreSysBackendCustomers\Infrastructure\EntityFramework\Persistence\Shared\MySQLRepository.cs:line 37
   at Application.Employees.EmployeeCreator.Create(Int32 createdBy, String name, String lastName, String phoneNumber, String cellPhoneNumber, String email, String user, String password, String identificationNumber, DateTime birthDate) in C:\PROGRAMACION\STORE\BACKEND\.NET 6\StoreSysBackendCustomers\StoreSysBackendCustomers\Application\Employees\EmployeeCreator.cs:line 16
   at StoreSysApp_Distribuidoras.ViewModels.PagesViewsModels.Login.LoginPageViewModel.GetAllEmployeesApi() in C:\PROGRAMACION\STORE\APPS MOVILES\AppLectorArticulo\StoreSysApp_Distribuidoras\StoreSysApp_Distribuidoras\ViewModels\PagesViewsModels\Login\LoginPageViewModel.cs:line 42
```

Los pasos que realice son los siguientes:

Por un lado obtengo desde una API que genere (con el mismo DbContext), un metodo en el cual devuelve todos los empleados (Employee), de esta forma yo recorro el resultado, y quiero grabar en el mismo DbContext (Pero en este caso lo llamo al context  desde mi app en .NET MAUI con una configuracion de SQLite) los registros del resultado que estoy recorriendo, y ahi es donde me arroja el error mencionado arriba.

Codigo en el cual obtengo el resultado de la API (MySQL) , y luego lo recorro para insertarlo en mi SQLite.

```
[RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(StatusConnection))]
private async Task GetAllEmployeesApi()
{
    try
    {
        var result = (await ServiceLocator.GetService<IGetEmployeeApiService>().GetAllEmployeesApiAsync()).ToList();
        foreach (var employee in result)
        {
            var db = ServiceLocator.GetService<StoreCustomersContext>();
            await ServiceLocator.GetService<EmployeeCreator>().Create(employee.CreatedBy, employee.Name, employee.LastName, employee.PhoneNumber, employee.CellPhoneNumber, employee.Email, employee.User, employee.Password, employee.IdentificationNumber, employee.BirthDate);
        }

        var resultSQLite = (await ServiceLocator.GetService<EmployeeSearcher>().GetAllEmployeesAsync()).ToList();
        await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Mensaje", "Personal actualizado correctamente.", "Aceptar");
        return;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        string msg = ex.Message;
    }

}
```

Edicion parte 2:

MySQLRepository:

Metodo que abarca la linea 37:

```
public async Task<T> Save(T entidad)
{
    try
    {

         T result;
         await entityStateModifiedManually(entidad);
         if (contexto.Entry(entidad).State == EntityState.Detached || contexto.Entry(entidad).State == EntityState.Added)
             result = (T)(await contexto.AddAsync(entidad)).Entity;
         else
             result = entidad;

         await contexto.SaveChangesAsync();

         return result;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
//LINEA 37
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

EmployeeCreator:

Metodo que abarca la linea 16:

```
public async Task<Employee> Create(int createdBy, string? name, string? lastName, string? phoneNumber, string? cellPhoneNumber, string? email, string? user, string? password, string? identificationNumber, DateTime birthDate)
{
    var employeeToCreate = new Employee(0,createdBy, name, lastName, phoneNumber, cellPhoneNumber, email, user.Trim().ToLower(), password.Trim().ToLower(),identificationNumber,birthDate.Date);
    return await _employeeRepository.Save(employeeToCreate);
}
```

La sintaxis es correcta, es decir el objeto "Employee", esta recibiendo correctamente sus parametros, y la interfaz "_employeeRepository", implementa los metodos genericos de MySQLRepository, que en este caso seria el save que esta mas arriba cuando puse el codigo de "MySQLRepository"

Gracias!

Comment: me tira error... que error?

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Punto 4 especialmente. Saludos :D

Comment: @fredyfx Gracias por responder, ahi edite la pregunta espero ser un poco mas claro con esta edicion.
Nuevamente gracias (:

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias por responder, ahi edite la pregunta espero ser un poco mas claro con esta edicion. Nuevamente gracias (:

Comment: Excelente, ahora, me gustaría saber qué hay en `MySQLRepository.cs:line 37` y `EmployeeCreator.cs:line 16` Gracias por tomar a bien las recomendaciones. :D

Comment: Hola, buenas noches @fredyfx , ahi lo volvi a editar, poniendo lo que hace cada metodo y una breve explicacino debajo de ellos, gracias por ayudarme con este problema (: !

Comment: antes del `throw ex`, coloca un `Debug.Print(ex.Message);` y veamos qué dice ese error en particular.

Comment: @fredyfx No me dice nada, el problema que arroja es el siguiente:
"An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details." 
Y el detalle es el que puse en la pregunta, no se que puede ser

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145174/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-alejo-moya).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que me sucedio, fue que estaba haciendo referencia a una .dll de mi proyecto de aplicacion incorrecta, es decir no se me actualizaba... modifique la referencia de proyecto y me anduvo bien.

Es decir, el problema era mio, el codigo esta bien hecho.

Comment: Entonces, por desgracia, tu pregunta carece de sentido.. no es un error que se pueda reproducir, y tu respuesta no aporta mucho ya que ni sabes que dll fallaba....

Comment: Si si, sabia la dll que faltaba, es por eso que estoy dando la respuesta... porque gracias a investigar y a la ayuda de fredy lo pude resolver, si no tuviera idea de la dll que faltaba no responderia sin saber. (:

Comment: si, tu si lo sabes, pero yo no. Tratamos de escribir preguntas y respuestas que ayuden a otros, no solo a uno mismo.